# How to label incoming but not outgoing emails in Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail

I tried to label emails containing a word in their subjects. The configuration is as

```
Matches: subject:(Cooking)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "Cooking", Never send it to Spam
```

but this labels my outgoing messages too, which are listed on the same label as unread messages. This makes a mess, as I want to check my new emails as unread messages. How can I tell Gmail to label only receiving emails, not those I compose.

Comment: Make it matches: subject:(Cooking) AND To: your email address? This should hit only the incoming messages... unless when you send out, you put your own email address on the To line... ?

Comment: @Darius I did this, but I hoped there is a more standard way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In conversation view (threaded) this only sort of can be done.

Labels are applied to individual messages.  If you search for a label in conversation view, it returns true if ANY message has that label.  Similarly if you search for -label it returns if ANY messaage in that thread does not have that label.

All searches work this way:  Boolean expressions are checked against each message, but the results for all messages in a thread are OR'd together when in conversation view.

One way to do what I think you want is to search for **is:unread**

You can combine this with a label, so  **label:cooking is:unread**

If you don't want to see your replies, set up a filter

**Matches: from:me@domain.com**
**Actions: mark as read**

Note that gmail does not guarantee order of filtering.  Filters can be applied in any order depending on some internal optimization scheme.